# Issue with .htaccess for friendly urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my currently my .htaccess file

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/edit/(\d+)?$ $1/edit.php?tag=$2 [NC]
```

As you can see it's set to hide the .php extension, but this then seems to break the edit rule.  If I comment out

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC]
```

The edit rule works fine, but I need both and cannot seem to get it to work, anyone see what the problem is and how to sort it.

**[Edit]**
I have a link like this and when all rules are active this is what doesn't work.

```
http://www.domainname.com/researcher/lists/edit/
```

and I get an 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: Rule order is significant. The rewrite log helps with overlapping patterns.

Comment: Tried putting RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC] last, seemed to make things worse, ended up with an Internal Server Error

Comment: Let me just mention the rewrite log, *again*. As mentioned in many other such questions, the catch-all `.*`  is least practical for overlapping rules. Certainly needs a last flag.

Comment: Could you elaborate please and provide an example of what you mean.  Not really done that much with this type of thing

Comment: Have updated my question to include more information

Comment: The digit at the end is optional.  Doesn't work with or without a digit

Comment: Where is your .htaccess located?

Comment: it is located at the root level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try rules as in your site root .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.+)/edit(?:/(\d+))?/?$ $1/edit.php?tag=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```